# What's wrong with my "proof" that the Lebesgue measure of $[0,1]$ is $0$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, fake-proofs

> **Proposition.** $\lambda [0,1] = 0$

*Proof.* Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary. We will prove that $\lambda[0,1] <\varepsilon$. Let $q : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ denote an injection with image equal to $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$. Let $p : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ denote a sequence with $\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} p_i < \varepsilon$. Then $$\lambda [0,1] = \lambda \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} (q_i+[-p_i/2,p_i/2]) \leq \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \lambda (q_i+[-p_i/2,p_i/2]) = \sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}} p_i < \varepsilon$$

So $\lambda[0,1] < \varepsilon$. Since this is true for all $\varepsilon>0$, we deduce that $$\lambda [0,1] = 0.$$

> **Question.** What gives?

Comment: So, how do you prove that $[0,1]=\bigcup[q_i-p_i/2,q_i+p_i/2]$?

Answer (score 4):

Yep. The fact that (in your notation)
$$
 [0,1] \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} (q_j - p_j/2,q_j+p_j/2)
$$
is untrue is classic fact one has to get past to begin to understand Lebesgue measure.

By picking $p_j = \epsilon/2^j$, you show exactly that there are open sets containing $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ with Lebesgue outer measure at most $\epsilon$. (In particular they are measurable and hence the complement is measurable with measure $> 1 - \epsilon$, so they certainly don't cover $[0,1]$! )

Comment: I think there is a typo in the equation you have written. From your equation and the wording after it, it appears that you  want to say, "the union of intervals $(q_{j} - p_{j}/2, q_{j} + p_{j}/2)$ is just the set of rationals in $[0, 1]$. This is wrong. Further OP is considering closed intervals centered at $q_{j}$.

Comment: You're right. Fixed it. The distinction between closed and open intervals isn't so important when you have flexibility to pick the p_j

Answer (score 2):

Looking at other answers and the discussions in comments here, it appears that the key issue here is not being handled properly. And previous version of my answer is perhaps not understood well by the community. What follows is an updated version with more explanation.

---

First some explanation about the question. The sequence $q_{i}$ is the just arrangement of rational numbers of $[0, 1]$ into a particular sequence (this is possible because rationals form a countable subset). Corresponding to a given $\epsilon > 0$ another sequence $p_{i}$ of positive real numbers is chosen so that $\sum_{i} p_{i} < \epsilon$. OP now argues that since the interval $[0, 1]$ is contained in the union $$\bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty}[q_{i} - p_{i}/2, q_{i} + p_{i}/2]$$ therefore its measure is not more than the sum of lengths of all these intervals $[q_{i} - p_{i}/2, q_{i} + p_{i}/2]$. And thus the measure of $[0, 1]$ is less than $\epsilon$ and since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary this means that $[0, 1]$ has measure $0$. And OP knows that he/she has committed a mistake somewhere because *it is common knowledge that measure of $[0, 1]$ is $1$*.

---

Most answers try to treat this in a high brow manner by saying that the proof is wrong because a sequence of intervals of total length $a$ cannot cover an interval of length $b$ if $a < b$. This fact appears obvious / intuitive but a proper proof depends on the nature of real numbers and specifically we need some powerful theorem like Heine Borel to handle this. *The same statement is trivial to prove if the sequence of intervals considered is finite*. It is *a common mistake in analysis* to extend the finitary arguments to situations where one is dealing with *infinite*. Most of the times this is possible but it has to be justified by a deeper analysis because in general it is not true. Thus for example finite sets are always countable, but there are infinite sets which are countable and there are also infinite sets which are uncountable.

Another issue is regarding the common knowledge that measure of $[0, 1]$ is $1$. This is the first fundamental theorem in measure theory which again appears intuitive/obvious but requires Heine Borel theorem (or its equivalent) for its proof.

All the answers agree that the problem with OP's proof lies in his assumption $$[0, 1] \subseteq \bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty}[q_{i} - p_{i}/2, q_{i} + p_{i}/2]\tag{1}$$ and yes this equation is wrong but this can not be proved by using measure theory and obtaining a contradiction like OP has done.

---

Let's assume equation $(1)$ and derive a contradiction using Heine Borel Theorem. Since the intervals $[q_{i} - p_{i}/2, q_{i} + p_{i}/2]$ under consideration are closed intervals, it may seem that Heine Borel is not applicable. But this issue is trivial to fix. Clearly we may have a problem only with the boundary points $q_{i} - p_{i}/2, q_{i} + p_{i}/2$ and the problem will occur only if the point is irrational (rationals are already covered by the intervals in equation $(1)$). And this is possible only when $p_{i}$ is irrational. Consider all these points of type $q_{i} - p_{i}/2, q_{i} + p_{i}/2$ where $p_{i}$ is irrational. These points form a countable set and hence we may have a countable set of points in $[0, 1]$ which do not lie in the interior of some interval $[q_{i} - p_{i}/2, q_{i} + p_{i}/2]$. We can cover these countable points with a sequence of open intervals whose total length does not exceed $\epsilon$. This new sequence of intervals together with $(q_{i} - p_{i}/2, q_{i} + p_{i}/2)$ (note the use of open intervals here) now forms an *open cover* for $[0, 1]$ and the total length of intervals in this cover is less than $2\epsilon$. Now we can apply the Heine Borel Theorem to reduce this to a finite cover for $[0, 1]$ and the total length of intervals included in the finite cover is less than $2\epsilon$. We get an obvious contradiction if $2\epsilon < 1$. It follows that the assumption $(1)$ is wrong. And that is the fault with OP's proof.

I urge readers to have a look at a [similar discussion where the OP is audacious enough to show that measure of whole real line is $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1780580/72031).

---

Comment: This would not be an open cover anyway, so why should it have a finite subcover?

Comment: @egreg : It does not matter that the cover consists of open intervals or not. What matters is that each point of $[0,1]$ lies in the interior of some interval centered at $q_{i} $. To make things more easy to state modern textbooks choose to deal with covers consisting of open intervals only.

Comment: The problem is that the OP has *not* defined a cover and you should make the further assumption that the interiors of those closed intervals cover.

Comment: @egreg: Please see my updated answer where I have given a simple fix for the problem you have mentioned.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I surely didn't downvote. To the contrary!

Comment: @egreg : I was not thinking of you (you are in  the group of MSE users whom I regard in high esteem) , but yes, looking at our comments people might feel that you were the downvoter. And thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 1):

By assuming that $\sum_{i}p_i<\epsilon$ you're effectively saying that the sum of the lengths of the interval $[-p_i/2,p_i/2]$ is $\epsilon$. In particular, for small $\epsilon$ this length is less then $1$, and so your intervals will never cover all of $[0,1]$.

Comment: Isn't that begging the question? If I fix a point $x \in [0,1]$ I can always find a rational point whose distance to $x$ is less than $p_i/2$, right?

Comment: Yes, but you have a fixed bijection between the $p_i$ and the $q_i$, so while there will be some rational number close enough to $x$, in general $q_i$ will not be close enough.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you!

Comment: This explains why OP can't be right, but does not explain what is wrong in OP's argument directly, which is of course (as one comment mentions) the fact that the "proof" assumes that the $[q_i-p_i/2,q_i+p_i/2]$ form a cover, when they don't.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo: The right tool here is to use Heine Borel theorem and get a contradiction as I have done in my answer. It is not possible to find fault in OP's argument via intuitive reasoning.

Comment: The fact that a sequence of intervals with total length $a$ cannot cover an interval of length $b$ where $b>a$ is obvious/intuitive but cannot be proved without the use of theorems like Heine Borel or its equivalent. In fact OP is exactly asking why this is not possible (but in a different way).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh OP already proved that his collection of open subsets is not a cover, by reaching a contradiction.

Comment: I don't think he proved this. He rather proves that these intervals do cover the interval $[0,1]$ and hence deduces that its measure is $0$ and asks to find fault with the proof. The fault is that such intervals can't form a cover of $[0, 1]$ but this can't be proved without some significant theorems like Heine Borel.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Have you ever heard of a proof by contradiction? He assumed they cover the unit interval, and reached a contradiction, namely that the measure of the unit interval is $0$. Hence his assumption that the intervals cover the unit interval was false. QED

Comment: OP is clearly asking "what is wrong with his proof?" and the fault is clearly the first assumption that the intervals do cover $[0,1]$. This fact is to be understood not via Lebesgue's measure theory because the theory itself is built on this fact.